# Swift Generics: No accessible initializers

Tags: generics, swift

Why does the code below compile with an error:
'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

```
let drive = Drive<Car>()

class Car : Steering {
    init() { }
    func turnWheel() { }
}

protocol Steering {
    func turnWheel()
}

class Drive<T:Steering> {    
    func Go() {
        var vehicle = T()
        vehicle.turnWheel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `T` is constrained to `Steering`. Your constraint says, "T can be any type that conforms to the `Steering` protocol. However, if I have this class:

```
class Airplane : Steering {
    init(altitude : Int) {
    }

    func turnWheel() {
    }
}
```

All of the sudden I have a type that conforms to `Steering` and `T`, but does not have an init that accepts zero parameters.

The solution is to add the init to your protocol, ensuring anything that conforms to it has the correct init.

```
protocol Steering {
    func turnWheel()
    init()
}
```

Comment: Thank you - only checked the other answer because it was two minutes sooner but still upvoted.

Comment: @LeeWhitney, Actually, mine was 2 minutes sooner (hover over the times to see the timestamps). Either way though, glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

You - as the compiler says - need to require a parameterless initializer in your declaration of `Steering`.

Since T is only required to implement the Steering protocol and you want to construct it using `T()`, the protocol `Steering` needs the parameterless initializer to be guaranteed to be constructable like that.

```
protocol Steering {
    init();
    func turnWheel()
}

class Car : Steering {
    required init() { }
    func turnWheel() { }
}
```